# SDK disponible para desarrollo secundario

Tags: java, sdk

Estoy tratando de comprar un periférico por internet pero necesito el SDK para java y en varios productos encuentro esa frase ¿que significa "SDK disponible para desarrollo secundario"?

Comment: Puedes poner una ejemplo de donde lo viste para revisar?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Significa que tu dispositivo provee algunas librerías para que puedas crear tu software personalizado y funcione perfectamentecon el susodicho dispositivo.

Debes revisar el sdk provisto ya que puede tener código en varios lenguajes, mi mejor sugerencia al respecto es que en caso de que no te provea librerías de Java, sino algún dll o algo similar, llames la librería del SDKmediante la interfaz nativa de Java o [jni](/questions/tagged/jni) por sus siglas en inglés.

Si no te da los dll, lib, so etc para reusarlos, deberás hacer un programa usando su sdk y llamarlo sus métodos desde java con el mismo JNI.

Comment: este es el producto que quiero comprar e incluirlo en un crud en java que estoy desarrollando y como puedes ver en las especificaciones dice lo de desarrollo secundario: https://www.amazon.es/KESOTO-Lector-de-Huellas-Dactilares/dp/B07G7X84K9/ref=sr_1_6?__mk_es_ES=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&keywords=lector+huella+digital&qid=1556908969&s=electronics-accessories&sr=1-6-catcorr